# How can I download image from url in js

Tags: javascript, html

I need to download image rom url.
I used a link tag for download. But it only download local images and not download  internet url files and instead open that image in browser.
If you know about this, please help me.

Here is the code I used:

```
<a href="https://www.enovaenergy.com.au/hs-fs/hubfs/Enova_July_2020/Images/Enova-Logotypes-02.png?width=624&amp;name=Enova-Logotypes-02.png" download>text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default for your image is to show it in the browser
The server needs to send

```
application/octet-stream
```

For the image to be downloaded